# How to buy ssl certificate programmatically?

Tags: ssl-certificate

Is there any API available to buy SSL certificates programmatically from some provider? If not, has anyone tried writing a bot to do this from a web interface? Assume it's OK to pre-charge balance on some account.

Comment: I'm sure, that those who have a reseller program also might have an API to make that easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few around. The one I remember off my head is NameCheap/SSLs.com https://www.namecheap.com/support/api/intro.aspx

Answer (score 2):

[LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) is generating a lot of buzz. Automated and free.

Still in limited beta for now but worth keeping an eye on.